# How to output PHP function within HEREDOC string 'HTML code' block

Tags: php, wordpress, heredoc, wordpress-shortcode

I have a wordpress plugin which, via a shortcode, outputs HTML via a HEREDOC string (EOD). For example:

```
<<<EOD
<div>
    <p>hi</p>
    $get_avatar($current_user->ID, 32) 
</div>
EOD;
```

My questions is, how can I run the get_avatar function, from within the HEREDOC string?
The paragraph tag contents displays but the PHP function output does not.

Comment: `$get_avatar` is a variable obviously.

Comment: Aah, i'm so stupid. I think the "penny has dropped"!

Answer (score 1):

The function calls are required before the HEREDOC...

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$avatar = get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 32 );

<<<EOD
<div>
    <p>hi</p>
    $avatar
</div>
EOD;
```